# Calling setState without triggering re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing a UI state in the React component's `state`, say `this.state.receivedElements` which is an array. I want re-renders whenever an element is pushed to `receivedElements`. My question is, can I **not trigger** rendering when the array becomes empty ?
Or in general, **can I call `setState()` just one time without re-render** while re-rendering all other times ? ( are there any options, work-arounds ? )
I've read through this thread: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8598 but didn't find anything.

Comment: Sounds like you want to hack the behaviour of your component. What do you think, how long will it last untill you'll need to hack the hack? Why don't you explain what exactly you're building and what problem you have. Or in other terms, what actual problem leads to this hack you're trying.

Comment: actually, I did not mean to _hack_.. I just wanted to know if I could avoid an unnecessary render... Nothing goes wrong even if render occurs :)

Comment: this should be solve by shouldComponentUpdate().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want re-renders whenever an element is pushed to `receivedElements`.

Note that you *won't* get a re-render if you use:

```
this.state.receivedElements.push(newElement); // WRONG
```

That violates the restriction that you must not directly modify state. You'd need:

```
this.setState(function(state) {
    return {receivedElements: state.receivedElements.concat([newElement])};
});
```

(It needs to be the callback version because it relies on the current state to set the new state.)

> My question is, can I not trigger rendering when the array becomes empty ?

Yes — by not calling `setState` in that case.

It sounds as though `receivedElements` shouldn't be part of your state, but instead information you manage separately and *reflect* in `state` as appropriate. For instance, you might have `receivedElements` on the component itself, and `displayedElements` on `state`. Then:

```
this.receivedElements.push(newElement);
this.setState({displayedElements: this.receivedElements.slice()});
```

...and

```
// (...some operation that removes from `receivedElements`...), then:
if (this.receivedElements.length) {
    this.setState({displayedElements: this.receivedElements.slice()});
}
```

Note how we don't call `setState` if `this.receivedElements` is empty.

Comment: while this solution works and new render won't be called, I would **strongly** advise against modifying state directly and using setState() every time. If for some reason you don't want to call render after state has been changed, you should use **shouldComponentUpdate** for that.

Comment: @patotoma: I disagree that the above should be avoided; if changes to the elements sometimes shouldn't be rendered, then in my view they shouldn't be part of `state`. [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), is another viable way to do this, though; you might post an answer about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder very explanatory! Thanks!! I already knew the bits about 'mutating state does not cause render' and 'it needs to be the callback version' but now I have a whole new perspective of what to store in `state` and what not to :)

Comment: @patotoma: I know about using `shouldComponentUpdate`.. it seems you didn't understand the (stupid ?) question that I have asked here.. I just wanted to know if I could skip just one render, or, if I could call `setState` without actually triggering a re-render just one time.

Answer (score 5):

What about `useRef`?

Documentation says:
*[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.*

So if you change ref value inside useEffect it won’t rerender component.

```
  const someValue = useRef(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    someValue.current++
  },[])
```

Comment: They have this trick in the docs, you could reference that as well https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables